# How I know if I have ECC RAM or not installed?

Tags: ecc

I have rent a server with: **8 GB DDR3-RAM ECC**

On startup the log files print something like this:

```
EDAC amd64: This node reports that Memory ECC is currently disabled, set F3x44[22] (0000:00:18.3).
Jan 15 03:24:44 big kernel: [   75.821734] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
Jan 15 03:24:44 big kernel: [   75.821736]  Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
```

Does this mean I have no ECC RAM, or is it just not enabled or.. ?
I have no physical access.... to the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just not enabled. You can force linux to load the module by issuing:

```
modprobe -v amd64_edac_mod
```

You can after check if it's enabled with:

```
dmesg | grep -i edac
```

and look for anything that says that ECC module is being loaded now.

But the best option is to enable it from the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

You could check your `BIOS`/settings. Most managed servers have access to these options. I have experience with dell servers where most have a `DRAC` (`Dell Remote Access Controller`) where I can access `BIOS` settings. Dell also provides a utility for their servers, I believe it was called Open Manage? Where limited settings were available. I'm sure if you contact your serverlord, they can provide you with access to these settings in some way.